# Gateway Timeout : 504 Error

Tags: joomla-3.x, file-upload

I am facing an issue with uploading an excel data sheet. The functionality is like

1. User uploads an excel sheet
2. Records are inserted into that custom component's tables by which graphs are shown in front-end. The tables contains all the calculation values for different years.
3. Then, for those records categories and articles are created.

But this works fine for small data sheets containing nearly 200 rows. Sometimes, step (2) works and it gets stuck in step (3). And sometimes, nothing works. When a sheet consists of more than 2000 rows then, half data is inserted and it gives me this error:

> Gateway Timeout - 504 error

I am using `phpexcel` for uploading excel to database and tried setting the following in the controller's upload task but still it is not working.

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('max_execution_time', 1800); //also tried set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
```

Kindly, guide to any solution

Comment: The question at: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11629945/1983389 might help

Comment: @NeilRobertson thanks for your response but I am using apache server. it's about nginx. I contacted the administrator and he has already increased the time on server as well but still facing this timeout.

Comment: Hi @Lisa, just suggesting it may be a server setting that needs to be updated rather than something that you can control via php.ini etc.

Comment: i crosschecked with the server guy and he said he has already increased the time on server :/

Answer (score 1):

Maybe look at other PHP values like **max_input_time** or some of the other suggestions in 
http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.common-pitfalls.php

> **max_input_time** sets the maximum time, in seconds, the script is
>   allowed to receive input; this includes file uploads. For large or
>   multiple files, or users on slower connections, the default of 60
>   seconds may be exceeded.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it is one of two things.

1) Hosting server does not have enough resources and you require and upgrade

2) Php.ini is usually the culprit but it seems you have addressed that.

Comment: i have already increased the timeout in the server

Comment: and what of your hosting..that is usually the only other reason. Not enough resources.